# Laravel changing primary key from URLs results in error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I changed my primary_key on my posts table from "id" to my "slug" column. That way my posts are accessible via /posts/slug instead of /posts/id. This brought me lots of issues, among one I cant solve: I have a like function on each post, which used to post to /posts/id/like. I tried changing this to /posts/slug/like which resulted in the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'likes.post_slug' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `likes` where `likes`.`post_slug` = test1 and `likes`.`post_slug` is not null and (`user_id` = 1) limit 1)
```

The problem is: I dont have a likes.post_slug column. Furthermore I never instructed my code to check for a "likes.post_slug" column. Before it probably posted to "likes.post_id" which indeed exists. So apparently Laravel is doing something there, which I dont know how to apply to my case now. I would like to get it to work, so that I can post to /posts/slug/like.
In the following I'm posting my code in the hope that someone might recognize what is off.
The routes:

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/like', [PostsLikeController::class, "store"]);
Route::delete('/posts/{post}/like', [PostsLikeController::class, "destroy"]);
```

PostsLikeController:

```
class PostsLikeController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Post $post)
    {
        $post->like(auth()->user());

        return back();
    }

    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $post->dislike(auth()->user());

        return back();
    }
}
```

My Like Methods:

```
trait Likable
{
public function scopeWithLikes(Builder $query)
{
    $query->leftJoinSub(
        'select post_id, sum(liked) likes, sum(!liked) dislikes from likes group by post_id',
        'likes',
        'likes.post_id',
        'id'
    );
}

public function isLikedBy(User $user)
{
    return (bool) $user->likes
        ->where('post_id', $this->id)
        ->where('liked', true)
        ->count();
}

public function isDislikedBy(User $user)
{
    return (bool) $user->likes
        ->where('post_id', $this->id)
        ->where('liked', false)
        ->count();
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
}

public function dislike($user = null)
{
    return $this->like($user, false);
}

public function like($user = null, $liked = true)
{
    $this->likes()->updateOrCreate(
        [
            'user_id' => $user ? $user->id : auth()->id(),
        ],
        [
            'liked' => $liked,
        ]
    );
}
```

}

The Like Class:

```
class Like extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

The Post Class:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Likable;
    protected $table = "posts";
    public $primaryKey = "slug";
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\User");
    }

}
```

The User Class (only relevant methods)

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Post");
}

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of my database table likes]

Comment: why in the workd you would fo that, besides that all references have to be checked, you have to rewrite all the queries. and you will loose performance

Comment: @nbk what do mean with "why in the workd you would fo that"? Do what?

Comment: i mean why do you change the primary key and i described what effort you have to make. there will be no gain with changing the priary key

Answer (score 0):

Don't freak out, the solution is actually simple.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys

All you need to do is to place the following line inside your `App/Models/Post`

```
protected $primaryKey = 'slug';
```

Then change the database column name in  your `Likes` Table from `post_id` to `post_slug`.

**Disclaimer** :  I don't agree with the OP that this is the best way to handle this kind of scenario, I am just trying to answer his/her question. I would not recommend that you use his/her code or mine.